# Unknown database 'mydatabase'. Error reoccurring on Amazon RDS mysql deployment

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu --version 12.04.4.

Hi,

I get the above error when i try to login into mysql on my Amazon deployment.The command i fire is as follows.

bitnami@ip-111-11-11-11:~$ mysql -u root --password 'mypassword'/ mysql -u root -p 'mypassword'
Enter password:
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'mypassword'.

Tried googling for similar errors but nothing relevant. 
Please observe it prompts for the password again and emits the error stating we are trying to connect to the database called mypassword.

Thanks for spending time.

Comment: Sooooooo, it says Unknown **database** but you provided a password. Now, how come you didn't deduce that you're passing the parameters to `mysql` program in the wrong order or in the wrong way? You tried googling for similar, how?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mysql -uroot -pmypassword db_name
```

or

```
mysql --user=root --password=mypassword db_name
```